# How to use sed on mac to delete part of a line and the next line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file which is saved output from an ASCII stream, so it's all text. I'm using a `bash` script with a sequence of `sed` statements on a mac to clean it up. There is one aspect of this that I'm stumped on.

In the file there are places where I need to delete part of a line to the end and the next line.

Example section of file:

```
abcdefg000

hijk
```

Should come out to:

```
abcdefg
hijk
```

Tried:

```
sed '/000/{N;d;}' FILE
```

That DOES delete the next blank line, but also deletes the first line. I end up with:

```
hijk
```

Since it's a mac I can't use sed to insert a newline (I've tried), but I have successfully replaced with a character and used `tr` to switch it out for a newline. Thought if I did that and since `tr` should take a string, include a special character, then I should be able to do the delete two lines sed and that would work.

```
sed 's/000/|/' FILE | tr '|' '\n|' | sed '/|/{N;d;}'
```

However, when I do this, I get only the newline and tr chops off the pipe. sed then doesn't find it and so doesn't delete any lines. I get:

```
abcdefg


hijk
```

`man tr` says it accepts a string, so not sure why it won't take `\n |` as a string.

I could redo this in some other language script, but I've spend long enough on it now and looked through enough other questions and answers that I want to get this to work. Either I'm missing something on `sed` or `tr` or there's some other simple way to do this.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you just want to clean up trailing `000` and newlines could you do something like `awk 'NF > 0 { sub(/000$/,""); print }'` ... Do you only want to clean up extraneous newlines after `000`?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet  That partially works - but it takes out ALL newlines. So there's no spaces between paragraphs at all. Only want to delete the newlines if after the 000.

Comment: can there be more than one newline after a `000`?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet In this case since I'm dealing with controlled input, no. It's just one newline after the 000 that I need to deal with.

Comment: `sed 's/000$//;tj;b;:j;n;d' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` should do a pretty good job of modifying the text file in the way that you want. Conditionally removing a single newline after a line ending with `000` is straightforward. We use a temporary variable `w` to control how many "lines ahead" we're able to delete blank lines from.

```
awk '/000$/ { sub(/000$/,""); w = NR + 1; } 
     NF == 0 && w < NR { next; } 
     { print; }'
```

And here's a way to do it if the script needs to handle the possibility of multiple newlines after a `000`. the interpretation of `d` is whether we're in a state where we're dropping blank lines or not.

```
awk '/000$/ {d=1;sub(/000$/,"");print;next;} 
     NF == 0 && d { next; } 
    { d = 0; print}'
```

You can coax `sed` into cleaning up newlines by swapping newlines with another character and then swapping back. Note that sed will, at least on OS X, add a trailing newline to the stream anyway, so you have to get rid of the stray `@` or `|` or whatever at the very end of the stream.

```
cat /tmp/data.txt | tr '\n@' '@\n' | sed 's/000@//' | \
    tr '\n@' '@\n' | sed '/^@$/d'
```

Here's how to compact multiple newlines after `000` to a single newline. Or one way to do it.

```
cat /tmp/data.txt | tr '\n@' '@\n' | sed 's/000@*/@/' | \
    tr '\n@' '@\n' | sed '/^@$/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed` on OSX:

```
sed '/000$/{s///;n;d;}' file
```

```
abcdefg000
hijk


foo

bar
```

Where original file is:

```
cat file
```

```
abcdefg000

hijk


foo

bar
```